# Google Protocol Buffers: find out what message is encoded in byte[]

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to find out what type of message is encoded in *byte[]*? I mean, is it possible to develop things like:

```
byte [] buf;

if (typeOfMessage(buf) == "AProto") {
  AProto.parseFrom(buf);
} else if (typeOfMessage(buf) == "BProto") {
  BProto.parseFrom(buf);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. Several different messages could all have the same `byte[]` representation. A message doesn't carry around with it any type information. The wire format indicates for each tag value what the encoding of the value is out of the various encodings, but that's as far as it goes.

If you *want* this functionality, however, it's relatively easy to wrap it up into your own message:

```
message MessageWithType {
  required string type_name = 1;
  required bytes data = 2;
}
```

Basically that just wraps each *real* message with the name of its type. This only works if you control the whole process, of course... if you don't get to change the data, you can't add that information.

As Kenton noted, with a fixed (and ideally small) set of types that you're interested in, you can declare a message with a field of each type (as per ursa's answer), using a `oneof` if you're using Protobuf 2.6.0+.

Comment: Note that if you have a small, known set of possible message types, a cleaner solution is to create a wrapper message with an optional field of each type. If using Protobuf 2.6.0, use the new `oneof` feature to indicate that exactly one field is filled in.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in the way you suggest. But there is a trick:

```
message DTO {
    // NOTE! The only and only message have to set.
    optional AProto aPhoto = 1;
    optional BPhoto bPhoto = 2;
    ...
    optional RenderRequest renderRequest = 20;
}
```

It adds some tech information into message, so you always know what you are working with.
Also it allows to track versioning, when incompatible changes happens:

```
message DTO {
    ...
    //optional BPhoto bPhoto = 2; // Compatibility broken in release 2014-10-09 by ursa
    optional BPhoto bPhoto = 21;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Got it. Means that you have to pass META as a separate data anyway(